# How to install different version of PHP (7 & 5.6) on Local WAMP server

Tags: php, apache, php-7

Currently I have installed PHP 5.6 on my Local windows 7 machine (x64). I have Manually installed PHP, Apache (2.4), MySQL and configured them to build my development server.

Now, I want to learn and test PHP 7, therefore I wanted to install it from http://windows.php.net/qa/ and configure it in such a way so that I can easily switch between PHP 5.6 and 7.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any clear information regarding this.

I am seeking help to setup my development environment, so that I can use multiple version of PHP including the latest PHP 7 RC.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to start developing using a VM (I suggest using Vagrant+Virtualbox) or Docker. Using isolated development environments leaves your computer free of clutter, you can develop in the same environment as production, and you're free to switch between different environments without breaking stuff.

Comment: As much as we all hate it, people use windows ... and PHP7 needs testing there too ... discourage people from deploying on windows, sure, but the more people that test there, the better ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are few option to do this

1. Install wamp *on your drive* and keep *another one as Protable*
2. Use two different servers. [wamp](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp) and [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)***(Note xampp still not upgrade to php-7 / 2015-10-13)***